# Nodejs build sublime-text2

Tags: node.js, build, sublimetext2

I am trying to use sublime-text 2, have installed Nodejs for Windows, the Nodejs plugin through package control and I get the following error:

> ERROR: The process "node.exe" not found.
>
> The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
>
> [Finished in 0.1s with exit code 1]

I have setup as my user environment variable a NODE_PATH: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe
There is in my System variables PATH: C:\Program Files\nodejs\

My Nodejs.sublime-settings is set-up as follows:

```
{
  // save before running commands
  "save_first": true,
  // if present, use this command instead of plain "node"
  // e.g. "/usr/bin/node" or "C:\bin\node.exe"
  "node_command": "C:/Program Files/nodejs/node.exe",
  // Same for NPM command
  "npm_command": false,
  // as 'NODE_PATH' environment variable for node runtime
  "node_path": "C:/Program Files/nodejs/node.exe",

  "expert_mode": false,

  "ouput_to_new_tab": false
}
```

My Nodejs.sublime-build is set-up as follows:

```
{
  "cmd": ["C:/Program Files/nodejs/node.exe", "$file"],
  "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
  "selector": "source.js",
  "shell":true,
  "encoding": "cp1252",
  "windows":
    {
        "cmd": ["taskkill /F /IM node.exe & node", "$file"]
    },
  "linux":
    {
        "cmd": ["killall node; node", "$file"]
    }
}
```

As a side note, I'm using JSHint which uses Nodejs using the same path (namely "C:/Program Files/nodejs/node.exe") and JSHint works!
Any idea why I can't use Nodejs build system?
Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting your build system just to the following for the time being:

```json
{
  "cmd": ["C:/Program Files/nodejs/node.exe", "$file"],
  "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
  "selector": "source.js",
  "shell":true,
}
```

Because you have a Windows-specific section, it's running that instead of the `"cmd"` on the first line of the build system. I suspect there's some sort of issue with the `taskkill` command.

If this does work, and you feel the need to have the `taskkill` section back in there, try restructuring it like so:

```json
"windows":
    {
        "cmd": ["taskkill", "/F", "/IM", "node.exe", "&", "C:/Program Files/nodejs/node.exe", "$file"],
        "shell": true
    }
```

Obviously, you don't need the linux section in there at all. I'm not too sure about the syntax on windows, you may need to have two ampersands `&&` there instead of one - I know that's the case on OS X and Linux systems.

Good luck!

Comment: I have implemented your amendments but then I got the following error: {'C:/Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.} and I saw on SO that on Windows the fact that there is a space in 'Program Files' produces many errors. I tried by using NODE_PATH as I had defined it in my environment variables but then Sublime printed the following error {'NODE_PATH' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file} I decided to replace 'NODE_PATH' with just 'node' and it finally worked!Thx Now have to check taskkill.

Comment: I believe I found what I was doing wrong. My goal was to test a small javascript expression like console.log("Hello!"); but I was using the nodejs build system, which launches a new process, that's why there is the taskkill command afterwards. So to test just JS I had to create a new JavaScript.sublime-build with {"cmd": ["node", "$file"]}, then restart and it works afterwards. You pointed me in the right direction.